# Pandas - filter dataframe with sorted index

Tags: python, pandas

I have this `df_player_means`, with 5 items:

```
Pierre-Emerick Aubameyang    0.629630
Sergio Aguero                0.592593
Danny Ings                   0.555556
Mohamed Salah                0.538462
Sadio Mane                   0.500000
```

And this `df_player_colors`, where all players and their respective colors appear multiple times, with 15k items:

```
Andrew Robertson      #CE1317
Dejan Lovren          #CE1317
Joel Matip            #CE1317
Joseph Gomez          #CE1317
Nathaniel Phillips    #CE1317
                       ...   
Michail Antonio       #7C2C3B
Nathan Holland        #7C2C3B
Pablo Fornals         #7C2C3B
Robert Snodgrass      #7C2C3B
Tomas Soucek          #7C2C3B
```

---

How do I filter `df_player_colors`, (or map `df_player_means` to `df_player_colors`), ending up with  `df_player_unique_colors`, with players from `df_player_means`, in that exact sorted order, alongside their respective colors?

I have tried:

```
 players = df_player_means.index

 df_player_unique_colors = df_player_colors[df_player_colors.index.isin(players)]
```

But colors being mapped are wrong..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IIUC, try with `join` and `drop_duplicates` maybe if you have duplicated colors for same player

```
df_player_means.to_frame(name='mean')\
               .join(df_player_colors.to_frame(name='color'), how='left')\
               .drop_duplicates()
```

or maybe with loc like:

```
df_player_colors.loc[df_player_means.index]
```

Comment: oh, I get `'Series' object has no attribute 'join'`

Comment: @8-BitBorges if they are Series, then use `to_frame` to be able to use join, see the edit